# Why is the core chat script stopping my entire game?

Tags: lua, roblox

```
15:49:30.355 - BackgroundImage is not a valid member of Frame
15:49:30.356 - Stack Begin
15:49:30.357 - Script 'Players.Crusade_Commander.PlayerScripts.ChatScript.ChatMain.ChannelsTab', Line 212 - method AnimGuiObjects
15:49:30.357 - Script 'Players.Crusade_Commander.PlayerScripts.ChatScript.ChatMain.ChannelsTab', Line 262 - method Update
15:49:30.358 - Script 'Players.Crusade_Commander.PlayerScripts.ChatScript.ChatMain.ChannelsBar', Line 352 - method Update
15:49:30.358 - Script 'Players.Crusade_Commander.PlayerScripts.ChatScript.ChatMain.ChatWindow', Line 634 - method Update
15:49:30.358 - Script 'Players.Crusade_Commander.PlayerScripts.ChatScript.ChatMain', Line 171
15:49:30.359 - Stack End
```

**This above was the error I have received**

---

After the error hits, almost all the running scripts freeze and stop working. The script that runs when this occurs is a simple camera manipulation with lerp() and by what I can tell, it only occurs when this script is running, but the thing is**I have made a new world, and put everything in there, still didnt work, checked for viruses, not the case, removed all frames in all the GUIs in my game, and it still remains like this.**
The line in the chat script thats causing this is:

```
self.SelectedFrame.BackgroundImage.BackgroundTransparency = self.AnimParams.Background_CurrentTransparency
```

And I cant simply change it because it only appears in game, or when you press play in studio, so you cant just change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error isn't anything to do with your code. The ChatScript is a script that Roblox has written and provides for free. It looks like they shipped a bug. If you want to disable in-game chat for testing and development try this.

Create a LocalScript in StarterPlayer > StarterPlayerScripts. Add this line :

```
game.StarterGui:SetCoreGuiEnabled(Enum.CoreGuiType.Chat, false)
```

This should prevent the ChatScript from being added to the player when they spawn. Roblox will have to fix this bug.

Comment: I believe it was both my code and the game so ill accept your answer.

Comment: it is surprising that this is preventing your other scripts from working. ChatMain - line 171 exists in a spawned function. so even if it threw errors, they shouldn't impact your game. Are any of your other scripts interacting with or relying on the chat scripts?

Comment: Nope not that I know of, I did avoid some of the scripts from stopping by using remote events but even then they still crash

Comment: I find out the problem, it was the game simply did not like me removing a local script that had active GUI in it.

Comment: In our case, it was that we were accidentally deleting `LocalPlayer.PlayerGui`.